# Punching holes in a shape that is already altered with pucker & bloat

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

I have a flower created with pucker and bloat applied to a pentagon. I am trying to punch out circles and ellipses from it to make areas of transparency for the stamens of the flower. However, when I try to use minus front shape mode with pathfinder, it punches out puckered/bloated shapes instead of the simple circles and ellipses I'm trying to use. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the shape and choose `Object > Expand Appearance` from the menu.

This will "bake in" the effect and remove the dynamic or "live" aspect of it.

Comment: Success! Thank you soooo much!